# Error while installing wso2 web services for php

Tags: php, ubuntu, wso2, wso2-wsas

I'm currently trying to install the wso2 php extension on an Ubuntu 12.04 server. When I do the 'make' command, I'm getting the following error:

```
Making all in savanc
/bin/sh: 18: cd: can't cd to savanc
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Fout 1
make[3]: Map '/home/devos50/Documenten/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.0.0/wsf_c' wordt verlaten
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Map '/home/devos50/Documenten/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.0.0/wsf_c' wordt verlaten
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Fout 1
make[1]: Map '/home/devos50/Documenten/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.0.0' wordt verlaten
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So the installer can't find savanc. I've been googling for this error and it seems to be working on php 5.2, however, I have some other services on my server running that requires php 5.3. How could I get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have sufficient right? try mkdir savanc before executing the make?

Comment: I'm running the command with sudo so I have enough rights. I will try to make the directory and I'll let you know if it has worked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed [this guide](http://patrics-it.blogspot.se/2012/03/how-to-install-wsowsf-210-for-php-on.html) with Ubuntu 12.04 PHP 5.3 and was able to install wso2 extension successfully. Maybe this will be helpful for you.

I should also warn you not to use this extension in production because of the following reasons:

- the latest commit to their repo was made almost a year ago
- there is no progress in their JIRA either for about a year
- the person who is set as a project manager for this project in jira seems to work on another project right now
- they are not responding to bug report in jira
- this extension has known stability issues on linux (check stackoverflow or their jira with keyworkds "wso2 php segmentation fault")

On the recent project we are also supposed to use wso2 php extension, but after some research we see that this extension is unstable and not supported anymore. Unfortunately, for now we do not know what to use instead and looking for some other solutions.