# Error while installing wso2 wsf/php on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, wso2

I'm currently trying to install the wso2 php extension on an Ubuntu 18.04 server with php5.6
When I do the 'make' command, I'm getting the following error:

```
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/mat/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/rampartc'
Making all in savanc
/bin/bash: line 17: cd: savanc: No such file or directory
Makefile:325: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mat/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c'
Makefile:221: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mat/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c'
Makefile:276: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mat/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0'
Makefile:206: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I really need to install this extension. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while installing wso2 web services for php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330375/error-while-installing-wso2-web-services-for-php)

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: It does answer your question, at least indirectly, even though it is not the answer you expected. Basically you are trying to install something totally outdated, non official, buggy, mostly undocumented, unmaintained and you shouldn't do it. Make is complaining about a folder which does not exist in your source archive. Even if you go over this problem (by downloading some other clunky forked version you could find), chances are you'll still hit a bunch of other compiling problems related to dependencies not being available anymore. Chances to get any support on this are close to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I really would find an up-to-date, official, not buggy version, but the company I would get the data with this web-service still use this.

Comment: Well then the company should provide the obsolete environment as a vm image, a docker image, a backup of some sort... to make sure you can install your environment as is expected and will probably never be found again without a very painful journey. I actually tried to compile your extension against a docker php:5.7 image. I stopped when it failed for because it expects a libssl version that is not available and full of security issues. It's probably possible to get that version with some digging. But there is no guarantee of success (and there might be many other libs with the same problem).

Comment: Thank you Zeitounator for your lights. I've passed a lot of painful journey trying to compile this bloody obsolete extension... but I really need to work with it. I will try to ask them if they don't have a vm image or something like this, because I think like you that I never be able to compile this extension again.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 no longer supports the WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP. Please see more details on this [page](https://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/wso2-attic/wsf).

If you have an active contract, or want one, please reach out to WSO2 to find an alternative approach.